# How to show / hide DataTemplates UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, uwp-xaml

I am busy with a UWP application. I have a grid view with Data Template item in it. it is set up as follows:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind location}">
 <GridView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate  x:Name="columnTemplate" x:DataType="data:Locations">
   <StackPanel x:Name="columnStack">
    <Image Width="100" Source="{x:Bind locationColumnImage}"/>
    <TextBlock FontSize ="16" Text ="{x:Bind numberOfBales}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>                           
   </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

It is bound from a class in the Models folder in my application..
and that class looks like this;
    public class locationManager

```
 {
    public  List<Locations> getLocations()
    {
        //represents db value of how many items in a particlar location
        var baleCol = buildColumnList(); 
        var location = new List<Locations>();
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "A", locationColumnImage = "Assets/A.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("A")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "B", locationColumnImage = "Assets/B.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("B")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "C", locationColumnImage = "Assets/c.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("C")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "D", locationColumnImage = "Assets/D.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("D")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "E", locationColumnImage = "Assets/E.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("E")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "F", locationColumnImage = "Assets/F.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("F")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "G", locationColumnImage = "Assets/G.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("G")).Count() });
  return Locations;
  }
 }
}
```

It is basically in a grid that displays an image a Letter (a to G) and below that letter a number(depending on how many /if any letter has an item stored in it's location A,B,C...)

What I want to know is if I did not want to show the items that have a 0 below the image (if nothing is stored in G don't display it) it how will I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your return statement instead of

```
return location;
```

change it to

```
return location.Where(a => a.numberOfBales > 0);
```

that way you will receive only those items with count > 0 and shows only those.